# Allow only 0 - 100 as percent values in form type

Tags: symfony

I have a percentage field in my form and I want it have values between 0 - 100 as number. How can I force it and return validation otherwise?

Currently I can even enter 100.10 which is wrong.

**Note**: 0.00 and 100.00 is allowed

Thanks

**ENTITY:**

```
/**
 * @var decimal
 * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=5, scale=2)
 */
protected $vatRate;
```

**FORM TYPE:**

```
->add(
'vatRate',
'percent',
array('type' => 'integer', 'attr' => array('min' => '0', 'max' =>` '100'))
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a [constraint](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints.html) to the entity

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/* ... */

/**
 * @var decimal
 * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=5, scale=2)
 * @Assert\Range(
 *      min = 0,
 *      max = 100,
 *      minMessage = "Min % is 0",
 *      maxMessage = "Max % is 100"
 * )
 */
 protected $vatRate;
```

Comment: ERROR: The option "type" has the value "percent", but is expected to be one of "fractional", "integer"

Comment: Yeah, sorry, in my haste I didn't see that you were already using the percent type, so I just removed that suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Use Range constraint in your entity:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Range.html

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @var decimal
 * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=5, scale=2)
 * @Assert\Range(
 *      min = 0,
 *      max = 100
 * )
 */
protected $vatRate;
```